# NSDatePicker is changing the time w.r.t system timezone. i want to stop changing the datepicker's date value

Tags: cocoa, datepicker, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My problem is that when I change the timezone using system preferences, the `NSDatePicker` date value is also changing. How can I prevent this and keep it as it is even though the timezone changes? Please suggest me how to achieve this.thanks in advance.

Comment: Experts pls help me,how to stop changing the time of NSDatePicker when TimeZone changes?

Answer (score 3):

```
NSLocale*  my24HourLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
[datePicker setLocale:my24HourLocale];
```

This will set the locale of the picker to UK 24 hour time. If you want 12hour time set it as "en_US".

If this doesnt work, then you can simply specify a fixed timezone for the picker. Best thing is to set the time zone as "GMT" so that if need arises it is easy for you to convert time in GMT to any other timezone.

```
[datePicker setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, My exact requirement is when the timezone changes, the datepicker should not change the time as well as the application should also take the time of the datepicker.  NSDate is automatically changing when timezone changes. do u have any thought for this. so i should prevent the entire application of time change but app dont mind about the date.

Comment: you can set timezone as GMT as given above. So even if timezone changes, GMT time will not change and still you can adhere to a standard. For this all you have to do is setTimeZone of datePicker to GMT and in the application, if you are using date formatter, set the timezone of date formatter also to GMT, but it maynot be necessary. Its what you want right?

Comment: i tried by setting the datepicker timezone to GMT as well as the application timezone to GMT but,the time difference is coming between the system time and application time.
I want to perform some operation when system time is equal to the datepicker's time , irrespective of the timezone.i.e, what ever the time zone if i want some operation at 10 PM the app should perform the operation at 10 PM at any timezone.

Comment: price:i did as you told , by trying to perform operation at 5:40PM ,datepicker time is also 5:40 but the app has taken 5:30 hrs less to the system time. I am using NSDate in my application . any solution for this. thank you for the reply

Comment: Are you using any dateFormatter anywhere? If so, try and set the timezone of the dateformatter in the same way using setTimeZone method and set that to GMT. You may be using system time elsewhere to update the application time and in that place, you need to set the time zone.

Comment: prince: i am using the setDate method to set the date of the date picker, so it is not taking the system current time instead it is taking the time as per GMT as i have set the timezone of datepicker to GMT. so now want the date picker to take the system time when i use setDate: , i am setting the datepicker time and i am taking the time from datepicker and storing it for comarision.

Comment: Prince thanks for reply,did u get my req : at any timezone i want to perform the operation at 10PM. even though the timezone change after setting operation time, the operation time should not change.but the application should follow the changed timezone

Comment: OK, now i'm confused! you need to take the GMT date from the date picker and store it somewhere. Then, you need to compare this date with the system date and if they are equal, you need to do some function. Am i right?

Comment: obviously yes, irrespective of the timezone the operation time should not change.but the application should follow the time zone and compare the operation time with current time with current zone.if both are equal ,perform the operation.

Comment: You are comparing the time of datepicker with time from system right. So i think you have two options. Either you need to do is convert the time from system also to GMT time. It will work. Or you can change timezone of datepicker from GMT to [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] but if you do this, datepicker time will vary with timezone but, still it will work too.

Comment: if i choose second one again the time of the datepicker will change. if i choose one the user is able to see the string value of date that the operation will happen at particular time, but the datepicker or the application's time will be different from the string. the diff is GMT OFFSET

Comment: Ok... I just thought of the third option. You will need to convert the GMT date you got from the datepicker back to the system timezone using systemTimeZone. Then you can compare them correctly right and both problems wont be there.